# VScode's debugger not working [MacOS - Clang - C]

Tags: c, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal

My problem is generated when trying to debug C (the programming language) in vscode using the latest MacOS version with command line tools installed.
The error appears when the external terminal is launched in order to debug. I'm using the clang compiler with the following configuration files for the debugger in vscode:

**launch.json**:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Open Terminal",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\"\ndo script \"echo hello\"\nend tell'",
        "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

**The error that appears in the terminal**:

username@Martins-MBP ~ %  cd ''; env 'USER=Martin' '__CFBundleIdentifier=com.microsoft.VSCode' 'COMMAND_MODE=unix2003' 'LOGNAME=Martin' 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ABVM6fu0pS/Listeners' 'SHELL=/bin/zsh' 'HOME=/Users/Martin' '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x2' 'TMPDIR=/var/folders/zb/b62pl9hd43n4chv3k7jg5cxr0000gn/T/' 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME=application.com.microsoft.VSCode.142509.142515' 'XPC_FLAGS=0x0' 'ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=undefined' 'SHLVL=0' 'PWD=/' 'OLDPWD=/' '_=/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron' 'APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL=true' '/bin/sh' '/var/folders/zb/b62pl9hd43n4chv3k7jg5cxr0000gn/T/Microsoft-MIEngine-Cmd-ukaihz0n.2gz'